# Seemingly random GAE Java error are destroying my SEO

Tags: java, google-app-engine, noclassdeffounderror

I'm getting the error

```
Error for /la/truckpage
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.google.apphosting.runtime.security.shared.stub.java.net.Proxy
```

For short spurts of time.  It will happen for 10 minutes, and then work fine for the next hour, only to happen again for another 5 minutes soon.  When the error happens, the user gets a 404.  On top of confusing the hell out of users, its awful for SEO.  There's NO REASON that this ought to be happening and it's really worrying considering all the other issues I've had with GAE.  I pay a whole lot of money every month to keep my app running on GAE and these arbitrary errors are absolutely unacceptable.

How can I fix this?

Comment: your tone is a little aggressive ("NO REASON", "pay a whole lot of money" etc) considering we're not the ones you are paying money to.  In fact, you are seeking (demanding?)  free help from us.  Take a deep breath, calm down, and focus on the technical aspects of the situation.  What have you tried so far in terms of tracking this issue down?

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, how much money are you paying?  If you are using more than the free quotas you may want to include that in the quetion (ie. Why am I getting errors with 4000 requests per second).  Is your app using tons of CPU? Memory? Datastore?  Have you tried a reserved instance?

Comment: It's not aggression, it's helplessness.  I can't identify the problem because it's not my fault.  One deployment may not work and the next one may, without any code modifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess would be that you hit momentarily resource quota or the DOS protection activates if you get usage spikes. Please read the [quota related documentation](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas.html), and the [DOS protection related documentation](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/dos.html).

GAE blocks your access to classes on purpose if you overstep the limits. Would be interesting to see what your application does with java.net.Proxy. It is probably doing something it should **not** be doing, at least not uncached and noncontrolled.